# exit button java

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, intellij-idea

I am building a Java GUI on IntelliJ and making an 'exit' button - currently using

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ItemEvent;
import java.awt.event.ItemListener;


public class gui extends JFrame {
    private JPanel mainPanel;

    private JButton exitButton;

    public gui(String title) {
        super(title);

        exitButton = new JButton("Exit");
        exitButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });

        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setContentPane(mainPanel);
        this.pack();
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new gui("Emro GUI");
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

The code runs, and I followed an exact tutorial on youtube, but the exit button isn't function how it should and I am unsure why. Should I have the exit button in a new class or function?

Comment: If you are using GUI designer in IntelliJ IDEA and bound the form button to the class filed, you don't need to initialize the button again in your code, so this line should be removed: `exitButton = new JButton("Exit");`.

Comment: *"but the exit button isn't function how it should"* and what's the current behavior? Also you don't need the `extends JFrame` part since you're not overriding its behavior. And please follow [Java naming conventions](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html) (`FirstWordUpperCaseClass`, `firstWordLowerCaseVariable`, `firstWordLowerCaseMethod()` and `ALL_WORDS_UPPER_CASE_CONSTANT`).

Answer (score 0):

Adding the following three lines in appropriate locations will make it work.

```
import javax.swing.*;
        mainPanel = new JPanel();
        mainPanel.add(exitButton);
```

However:

- Swing should always be used from the AWT Event Dispatch Thread (EDT) (use `java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater`.
- No need to extend `JFrame`.
- No need for `mainPanel` and `exitButton` to be fields instead of locals.
- Use a lambda expression for the `ActionListener`.

Comment: "No need for mainPanel and exitButton to be fields instead of locals". It's not true when using IntelliJ IDEA GUI designer which generates the code initializing these fields for the user. The question indicates that GUI designer is used, see my comment for the possible reason of the issue.

Comment: @CrazyCoder Although you may not be able to do anything about it, these are all valid points and I would suggest using not using the GUI designer as you learn more and have better control of your code, cant believe a designer generates such shit code, but either way no need for the downvote, all are valid points to keep in mind. +1

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this inside your action listeners method:

`WindowEvent closeWindowEvent = new WindowEvent(frame, WindowEvent.WINDOW_CLOSING); frame.dispatchEvent(closeWindowEvent);`

Comment: Never realized this question was so old . Leaving here for future reference.